# Managing a buffer using inputted data from a serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I'm writing an application that will read a continuous stream of data from a microcontroller via the serial port and then process the information it provides. I'm trying to read all the data via `SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync` and then store that data into a global buffer so that I can the process the data being received. However, I'm not sure what data structure I should use for the buffer. I've seen some stuff about circular buffers, which seem like they could work, but they appear difficult to program. I then thought of using a linked list: I think that it might be able to work, since I could keep adding new data to the end of the list, and have a function that processes the data continually check for data in the buffer and read the data from the front and then delete it. However, I would probably have to keep the size of it in check by deleting data from the front if it gets too large due to me processing it too slow for some reason, right? Also, is there any issue with having to remove items from memory when I remove the first items? I guess, in a way I'm just trying to make a circular buffer from a linked list, and I'm not sure if that's a good way to tackle this. If you guys have any suggestions I would appreciate it!

Comment: I would use a List<Byte> so you are easily add more data to the end and remove data from beginning.

Comment: Just for info: Usually circulair buffers are typically used when handling continuous signals.

Comment: @jdweng I thought of doing that, but one thing I saw seemed to say that removing stuff from the beginning of a list is pretty slow, and a linked list would be much faster for doing that since lists are based around arrays so when you add/remove items you have to copy the array to a new one

Comment: Why can't you just treat it as a stream, using the normal stream handling classes?

Comment: @SteveTodd that's an interesting idea, but I looked into it and I think that removing items from the beginning of a stream requires copying the stream over to a new one, is that correct? I feel like that would be really slow       EDIT: Actually wait, I'm not sure if I really even understand how a stream works. I saw someone give it an analogy like a hose, and if that's the case it's basically what I want. Is that correct? I'm having a hard time finding information on how it works

Comment: Data may not come in one chunk due to the windows driver working off of timers.  So with continuous data you may need to read only some of the data from the buffer (up to end of line or size of message) while you are getting new data that gets added to the end.  Linked list would be no different in the time.

Comment: @jdweng so what you're saying is, I'm gonna end up waiting for data at some point anyways, so the time needed for the removals isn't going to matter as much, and List<Byte> will be easier to work with than a linked list?

Comment: You should use the `DataReceived` event built into the `SerialPort` class.  It fires when new data comes in.  When that happens you build a string or array of characters and check to see if you have everything you need.  Once you do, you evaluate it and clear the array/string.  I work with microcontrollers for a living and I do pretty much everything in ASCII/strings.  `serialPort1.ReadExisting()` will give you the existing ASCII characters in the buffer.  Let the class do the work for you, no need to re-invent it.

Comment: I do not know what a link list would do to solve the issue.  You have to frame the data and the List<Byte> is the easiest method to do the framing.  I do not know the speed of the input so do not know anything about the wait time.  Just the data rate has to be less than the process rate.

Comment: @Baddack I was going to, but then I saw [this](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport) that indicates it's riddled with flaws, so I decided to be safe and use basestream

Comment: @jdweng that's fair, I think I'll use a List then, thanks for the help!